# What is the point of setting an attribute of class equal to output of a method of the same class?

Tags: python, c++, class, oop, design-patterns

This question should pertain to all OOP languages, though I'm only familiar with C++ and Python. I've seen this in several codebases and have seen this in Python and I think also in C++. I will illustrate in Python:

```py
class sim:
  def __init__(self, name="sim_today"):
    self.name = name
    self.properties = self.compute_properties()
  def compute_properties(self):
    # <insert logic to compute properties>
    return properties
```

I don't understand this type of design. Why not just set `properties` directly within `compute_properties` like:

```py
class sim:
  def __init__(self, name="sim_today"):
    self.name = name
    self.compute_properties()
  def compute_properties(self):
    self.properties = <insert logic to compute properties>
```

Comment: I don't see why you would do _either_ of those if the intent was to demonstrate OOP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would you do it then?

Comment: I think the way most people would do this is with subclasses.

Comment: @Mark I see what you're saying and I realized I provided a poor example that could benefit from inheritance. That point was to just ask what is the point of not just setting the attribute directly in the method instead of returning a temporary and assigning it to the attribute

Comment: @Mark I changed the example

Comment: *and I think also in C++* -- If you would have posted a C++ example, that would have been better, or at the very least, your tagging of the question would be appropriate.  If you're really not sure about C++, you shouldn't tag C++.  Not every C++ programmer knows Python or what that code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns suggests that a method should generally return a value or mutate the object but not both.  The constructor is the obvious place to initialize the object’s attributes, and this design makes it clear that what is conditional is **what** value is assigned and not anything more general like selecting an attribute or not assigning anything.

Of course, when the value can be computed from other attributes, that makes the one assigned a **cache**; recall that cache invalidation is one of the two hard things in computer science (along with naming things and off-by-one errors), so this would be justified only if the value were expensive to compute.